# Abrir nova janela JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de abrir uma nova janela em um aplicativo desenvolvido com Ionic framework.

html

```
<a href="{{exemplo}}">Abrir </a>
```

java script

```
exemplo = window.open("google.com");
```

Eu gostaria de abrir quando eu clicasse no link "abrir", o que acontece agora é que quando eu carrego a pagina já está abrindo a nova janela.

Comment: Seja mais objetivo, fale o que está usando, que é um aplicativo híbrido com Ionic, etc

Comment: Usar somente <a href="endereço" target="_blank">abrir</a> não serve?

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir links externos dentro de um aplicativo sendo desenvolvido com Ionic, utilize o plugin Cordova InAppBrowser que pode ser usado para abrir imagens, acessar páginas web e abrir arquivos PDf.

O plugin pode ser instalado pelo seguinte comando:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Para instalar e configurar o plugin na aplicação com ngCordova, [mais informações aqui](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/).

### Exemplo:

Código da view:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController" padding="true">
        <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="openInExternalBrowser()">
            Browser do sistema
        </button>
        <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="openInAppBrowser()">
            Nova instância inAppBrowser
        </button>
         <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="openCordovaWebView()">
            Cordova Webview
        </button>
</ion-content>
```

Código do controller:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.controller("ExampleController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.openInExternalBrowser = function()
    {
        window.open('http://google.com','_system','location=yes'); 
    };

    $scope.openInAppBrowser = function()
    {
        window.open('http://google.com','_blank'); 
    };

    $scope.openCordovaWebView = function()
    {
        window.open('http://google.com','_self'); 
    };

});
```

### Entendendo melhor:

**_blank:** Ele abre a URL no inAppBrowser

**_self:** Abre na Cordova WebView se a URL está na white list, senão ele abre no InAppBrowser.

**_system:** Abre no browser do sistema.

**location=yes:** Mostra a URL completa da página no InAppBrowser em uma barra de endereço, por padrão `location` é configurado para `no`.

### Eventos:

Esse plugin possui eventos combinados com o `$rootScope`:

**Ao começar abrir paǵina:**

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function(e, event));
```

Evento chamado quando o InAppBrowser começa abrir a página.

**Ao terminar de carregar:**

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event));
```

Evento que dispara depois que o Browser terminou de carregar a página.

**Ao dar erro ao carregar:**

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function(e, event));
```

Evento disparado quando o InAppBrowser encontra um erro ao abrir a URL.

**Ao fehar a janela:**

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:exit', function(e, event));
```

Evento disparado quando a janela do InAppBrowser é fechada.

**Exemplo com evento terminar de carregar página:**

Injeta um css e javascript na página carregada

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){

   //insere um css por código
   $cordovaInAppBrowser.insertCSS({
     code: 'body {background-color:blue;}'
   });

   // insere um Javascript por arquivo
   $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript({
     file: 'script.js'
   });

   alert("Página carregada");
});
```

Comment: Glauber a chamada do $rootScope.$on será no .controller ou no .factory?